# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when trying to write a message JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

[See this pic for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DA0z.png)

When i try to write a message it crashes. I can't seem to find the error here. i get a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC)_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0.` I'm trying to find what is the problem on my string. Sorry I'm just new on xcode

Full code is on below

```
import UIKit
import JSQMessagesViewController
import MobileCoreServices
import AVKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class ChatViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {
    var messages = [JSQMessage]()

    var messageRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages")


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.senderId = "1"
        self.senderDisplayName = "Ej"
        //messageRef.childByAutoId().setValue("first message")
        //messageRef.childByAutoId().setValue("2nd")
//        messageRef.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
//            if let dick = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
//                print(dick)
//            }
//        }
        observeMessages()


    }

    func observeMessages(){

        messageRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            //print(snapshot.value)

                if let dick = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                //let Mediatype = dick["Mediatype"] as! String
                let senderId = dick["senderId"] as! String
                let senderName = dick["senderName"] as! String
                let text = dick["text"] as! String  
                self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, text: text))
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

    //Send Btn
    override func didPressSendButton(button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: NSDate!) {

    //Messages
        //messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderDisplayName, text: text))
       //self.collectionView.reloadData()
//        print(messages)

        let newMessage = messageRef.childByAutoId()
        let messageData = ["text": text, "senderId": senderId, "senderName": senderDisplayName, "Mediatype": "TEXT"]
        newMessage.setValue(messageData)



    }
    //File btn
    override func didPressAccessoryButton(sender: UIButton!) {
        // ALERT WHEN PRESSED ACCESSORY
        let sheet = UIAlertController(title: "Media Messages", message: "Select A Media", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (alert:UIAlertAction) in

        }

        let photoLibrary = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction) in
            self.getMediaFrom(kUTTypeImage)
        }

        let videoLibrary = UIAlertAction(title: "Video Library", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction) in
            self.getMediaFrom(kUTTypeMovie)


        }

        sheet.addAction(photoLibrary)
        sheet.addAction(videoLibrary)
        sheet.addAction(cancel)
        self.presentViewController(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)



        //let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        //imagePicker.delegate = self
        //self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }

    func getMediaFrom(type: CFString) {
        print(type)
        let mediaPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        mediaPicker.delegate = self
        mediaPicker.mediaTypes = [type as String]
        self.presentViewController(mediaPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)



    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
        return messages[indexPath.item]
    }

    //BUBBLE CHAT
    override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
        let bubbleFactory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()
        return  bubbleFactory.outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(.lightGrayColor())
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
        return nil
    }





    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("number of items  \(messages.count)")
        return messages.count
    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

        return cell
    }


   override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

        print("didTappedMessageBubbleAtIndexPath \(indexPath.item)")
        let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    if message.isMediaMessage {
        if let mediaitem = message.media as? JSQVideoMediaItem{
            let player = AVPlayer(URL: mediaitem.fileURL)
            let playerView = AVPlayerViewController()
            playerView.player = player

            self.presentViewController(playerView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func LogOutTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
       print ("User Logged Out")
        //Goes on to Chat View




        //Main Stroryboard Interface
        _ = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)



        //From MainStoryboard instatiate a navigation controller

        let LoginVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginVC") as! LogInViewController



        //Get app delegate

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate




        //Navigation Controller as root view controller

        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = LoginVC


    }


}


extension ChatViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        print("finish picking")
        print(info)
        if let picture = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            let photo = JSQPhotoMediaItem(image: picture)
            messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderDisplayName, media: photo))
        }else if let video = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL{
            let videoitem = JSQVideoMediaItem(fileURL: video, isReadyToPlay: true)
            messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderDisplayName, media: videoitem))
        }

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }



}
```

Comment: You may want to clean up your print statements `print("finish picking bastard")` 

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `dick["text"]` is actually an unexpected nil.

Try doing this:

```
let text = dick["text"] ?? ""
```

which should replace the nil with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look in to the `guard` statement. This is a statement that lets you check for the value of an optional "?" and if it is nil then it handles that situation because if you do not have all the required information of a messages I.E. if the messages has no text you do not want to show it in the conversation. It is very similar to the `if let` Statement that you have already but makes it so you do not have to nest `if let` inside of `if let`
 So I would suggest changing you logic to something more like this.

```
messageRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
   guard let dick = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return } 
     // This will return if the snapshot cannot be mapped to the dictionary format [String: AnyObject]    
   guard let senderId = dick["senderId"] as! String, senderName = dick["senderName"] as! String, text = dick["text"] as! String else { return } 
     // This will return if the "dick" object does not contain all the elements necessary to create a JSQMessage
     // Otherwise we want to add it to our messages list   
            self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, text: text))
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
```

Now you also may want to look into this logic. Your `dick` object seems more like a general message object. regardless of "dick" having been the person who sent the message or not. Unless you are referencing "dick" specifically through your path to `firebase`. From the looks of it tho this line `var messageRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages")` I assume it is just where you are storing all messages on your backend. 
I may not fully under stand the purpose here but I hope that helps. Let me know if you have further questions.